# Installed jenkins via the repo, What server is it running? jetty? tomcat? something else completely?

Tags: linux, security, jenkins, networking, system-administration

Q1
I installed jenkins on linux using the jenkins repo. It's up and running fine. I thought it was running on nginx or apache so I could change the hostname and install certificates but I read somewhere that it's most likely using a small java servlet called jetty???? I'm a devops student and want to go about this the right way for future production workloads. Is there a way to access the jetty server to make production ready network and security updates? Should I instead redo the server and install jenkins on tomcat so I can make these changes? Orrrrr, should I install nginx alongside whatever is running jenkins? TIA.

Q2
I tried systemctl status nginx, httpd, tomcat, tc, http, apache2, jetty. How do you find what server is running jenkins. I assume there may be a java command that could tell me where the jenkins.war is being served from?

Answer (score 0):

1.Jenkins is a java application, so it will use a java servlet container.  By default, it uses Jetty, but you can also use Tomcat.  If you want to use nginx,
you'll need to configure it to reverse proxy to the servlet container.

2.You can find the process running Jenkins by running `ps -ef | grep jenkins`. This will give you a list of all processes running on your system that contain the word "jenkins". The first column is the process ID, and the second column is the command that started the process.